# vb console application does not close

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I created a vb.net to grab an attribute from AD and create a local variable.
It does that just fine, the problem is that it leaves the console window open with nothing but a flashing cursor. Ideally it would close as soon as it created the variable.

I've tried adding Environment.Exit (0)

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim objShell
    Dim objUserEnv
    Dim objADSysInfo
    Dim objUser

    objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    objUserEnv = objShell.Environment("USER")
    objADSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
    objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objADSysInfo.UserName)
    ' This will create the variable %ipphone%
    objUserEnv("ipphone") = objUser.ipPhone

End Sub

End Module
```

Any ideas why it's not closing the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Since `Environment.Exit(0)` is not working and you are within a Console application, Try this,
 Go to `Project` > `Add Reference` > `Assemblies` > `Framework` and search for `System.Windows.Forms` click the check box and then click the `Ok` after that add this to your code.

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Module Module1

Sub Main()

    Dim objShell
    Dim objUserEnv
    Dim objADSysInfo
    Dim objUser

    objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    objUserEnv = objShell.Environment("USER")
    objADSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
    objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objADSysInfo.UserName)
    ' This will create the variable %ipphone%
    objUserEnv("ipphone") = objUser.ipPhone
    Application.Exit()
End Sub
End Module
```

Another reason that it might not be closing is because it is not completing the task, When I ran your code, It didnt complete and I got this error

`Additional information: No mapping between account names and security IDs was done. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070534)` 
 Since you didn't mention this in your question, Im guessing you didnt get this error?

Comment: It's definitely working. You would need to run it while logged into a domain account while connected to the domain for it to function though.
Following your suggestion gives the same result though.

Comment: What happens when you step through it line by line?

Comment: Thanks Werdna. Turns out it is working and I was just being impatient.

Comment: no problem at all, If you found my answer / comments some what helpful, please mark it correct for the next person :) yeah, sometimes I add something like this to my code if I know if is going to take time `Console.WriteLine("Loading Please Wait....)`

Answer (score 0):

Module MyApp

```
Sub Main()
    ' Attach the event handler method
   AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit, AddressOf MyApp_ProcessExit

   Dim objShell
   Dim objUserEnv
   Dim objADSysInfo
   Dim objUser

   objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   objUserEnv = objShell.Environment("USER")
   objADSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
   objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objADSysInfo.UserName)
   ' This will create the variable %ipphone%
    objUserEnv("ipphone") = objUser.ipPhone

    Environment.Exit(0)
End Sub

Private Sub MyApp_ProcessExit(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine("App Is Exiting...")
End Sub
```

End Module

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Application.Exit
```

I think it's cause of the settings of your project, I never had such a matter

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was just impatient and it does close given enough time.